# $V{REPORT_COUNT} start at 1

Tags: count, jasper-reports

*JasperReports* iReport $V{REPORT_COUNT} is starting at 0 instead of 1

How can i make it start at 1 rather than 0

I think this is a setting in th properties but not 100% sure, may be in the XML

**Question is basic but not meeting minimum length**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just used `$V{REPORT_COUNT} + 1` to make it start at 1